# Java Extract a String from a String

Tags: java, string, split

I am parsing a csv file with Apache Commons CSVRecord and CSVFormat in Java
I got the following record in String format
Records :  CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={Id=0, FirstName=1, LastName=2}, 
recordNumber=1, values=[1, John, Wayne]]

I need to extract the values only For ex: 1, John, Wayne

Used the following options to get the result.

```
String[] split = record.split("values=\\[");
String result = split[1].substring(0, split[1].length() - 2);
```

My Question is: Is there a better option(Faster) than this in Java?

Comment: Could you please paste an example of your input csv file?

Comment: Are you trying to parse `CSVRecord.toString()` value? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: What Karol said. Use one of the `CSVRecord.get()` methods or the `CSVRecord.iterator()` or `CSVRecord.toMap()` to acces the values

Comment: Yes. I am trying to parse the CSVRecord.toString() value

Comment: maybe you can use method `toMap()` on your `CSVRecord` then you'll have `Map<String,String>` and you'll access directly your `FirstName` and `LastName`

Comment: Which option is better out of the two:
1. Construct a string by appending (CSVRecord.get methods for each record)
2. Option I've tried in the question

Comment: Trying to parse from the string representation has pitfalls in addition to being less performant. For instance @Guilherme's solution will fail if one of the values contains `values=[` or `,` (the first one is unlikely, the second maybe less)

Comment: Option 1.Construct a string by appending (CSVRecord.get methods for each record) - Is it Not be less performant than this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String txt = "CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={Id=0, FirstName=1, LastName=2}, recordNumber=1, values=[1, John, Wayne]]";

String[] sub = txt.substring(txt.indexOf("values=[")).split("[\\[\\]]");


System.out.println(sub[1]);
```